# How can make the logic avoiding discrete derivative in the when clause in Modelica?

Tags: modelica, derivative, dymola

i'm making the logic calculating the p(pressure) of the internal combustion engine.
equations consist of several cases called 'Period' in when clause.

```
  when Period==1 then
    p = pre(p) * ( T / pre(T)) ^( Gamma/(Gamma-1));
  elsewhen Period==0 or Period==2 or Period==3 then
    p = ( m*R_gas*der(T)+m*T*der(R_gas)+R_gas*T*der(m)-V*der(p) ) / der(V);
  end when;
```

the only unknown variable in the code is p and i got the error messages like below

[image]

In the message said that equation p is discrete and cannot be differentiated.

But, i thought that it's not discrete equations.
Even Though it is discrete equations, i don't expect the error because der(p) part is only in the second clause.

How can i fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you explain what behavior you want?

The 1st equation,

```
  when Period==1 then
    p = pre(p) * ( T / pre(T)) ^( Gamma/(Gamma-1));
```

works on its own, but the 2nd equation above for p will only be active when Period *becomes* 0, 2, or 3. That is just a single point in time, so I cannot understand what der(p) should be in that right-hand-side.

Additionally if an equation involves both `p` and `der(p)` the equation is normally solved to compute `der(p)` based on `p`, but I'm not sure if that is the goal here.

Added:
Your comments seem to indicate that you want the equation to be valid while Period gets a new value and not only when at an instance. In Modelica `when` for equations that only should be valid once when the condition becomes true, and `if` is for equations that are valid while the condition is true.

That would lead to something like:

```
  if Period==1 then
    ...
  else
    p = ( m*R_gas*der(T)+m*T*der(R_gas)+R_gas*T*der(m)-V*der(p) ) / der(V);
  end if;
```

However, the first equation is problematic in that case. I guess you want `x=T^(Gamma/(Gamma-1))/p` to remain constant in that part, and unfortunately writing that directly would lead to changing index which is currently not supported in Modelica.

However, an alternative is to say that it has zero derivative, and that would give something like:

```
  x=T^(Gamma/(Gamma-1))/p;
  if Period==1 then
    der(x)=0;
  else
    p = ( m*R_gas*der(T)+m*T*der(R_gas)+R_gas*T*der(m)-V*der(p) ) / der(V);
  end if;
```

But it is not certain that it will work, as I haven't seen the entire model.

Comment: when 0<thetta and thetta<=180 then
    Period=0;
  elsewhen 180<thetta and thetta<=360 then
    Period=1;
  elsewhen 360<thetta and thetta<=540 then
    Period=2; 
  elsewhen 540<thetta and thetta<=720 then
    Period=3;
  end when;

Comment: Period is the flag designating the range of the rotate angle of engine. and 0.01 second matches 180 deg angle. So i thought that it's not the single point in time. How do you think?

Comment: I want model works with first clause equation in 0 to 180 deg and second clause equation in the other angles.